# Record SSH / Terminal into video?

Tags: linux, ssh, monitoring, terminal, system-monitoring

If someone access to the server via Putty (SSH) or terminal - I want to record everything  what they can see on the screen and what they have typed into video..

What is the solution to this, is there a software that can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log every command executed from root](http://serverfault.com/questions/378305/log-every-command-executed-from-root)

Comment: In short - no, there's nothing that will be able to record an actual video of remote ssh sessions. However, the `sudosh` solution given in the above linked QA can accomplish nearly the same thing.

Comment: @ErikA I just found http://www.observeit-sys.com/Products/UnixAuditor can do this job I think

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this for auditing or security?  What is the intended use case?

Comment: Is this supposed to be for creating some kind of training?  There are many screen capture tools.

Answer (score 2):

What you can use is:

http://www.observeit-sys.com/

It is free for a limited number of servers, I use it to monitor our Citrix servers and it runs very well, with a nice UI.

One major drawback is the amount of sales calls and emails you will recieve when you download this!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `script` utility that can write into the file everything from terminal.
just set user's shell to the `script -akq /audit/username.log bash` and you'll get full log for keys pressed and data displayed. But don't forget to rotate that log.