# How can I log users' bash commands?

Tags: security, debian

I'm running a debian etch server where users will be logging into (hopefully) a chroot jail through ssh. How can I have the commands they execute logged in a way they cannot delete, nor prevent?

Comment: see this question http://serverfault.com/questions/8851/live-view-of-linux-shell-commands-executed-by-another-user

Answer (score 11, accepted):

install [snoopy](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/88). If you only want to log the one user, do some syslog filtering fu.

Comment: I want to log every user.

Comment: Then just install it, it'll "just work" (TM)

Comment: can I set it to log somewhere besides /var/log/auth.log?

Comment: It goes to syslog, so you can filter it to wherever from there, iirc. I've only ever done anything with syslog-ng, so I've no idea about filters with regular syslog I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a method to log all 'bash' commands/builtins into a text-file or a 'syslog' server without using a patch or a special executable tool.

It is very easy to deploy, as it is a simple shellscript that need to be called once at the initialization of the 'bash'. (just 'source' it from .bashrc for example)
It is based on the idea of using bash DEBUG traps. See also [this post on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command)

```
declare -rx HISTCONTROL=""                                  #does not ignore spaces or duplicates
declare -rx HISTIGNORE=""                                   #does not ignore patterns
declare -rx AUDIT_LOGINUSER="$(who -mu | awk '{print $1}')"
declare -rx AUDIT_LOGINPID="$(who -mu | awk '{print $6}')"
declare -rx AUDIT_USER="$USER"                              #defined by pam during su/sudo
declare -rx AUDIT_PID="$$"
declare -rx AUDIT_TTY="$(who -mu | awk '{print $2}')"
declare -rx AUDIT_SSH="$([ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] && echo "$SSH_CONNECTION" | awk '{print $1":"$2"->"$3":"$4}')"
declare -rx AUDIT_STR="[audit $AUDIT_LOGINUSER/$AUDIT_LOGINPID as $AUDIT_USER/$AUDIT_PID on $AUDIT_TTY/$AUDIT_SSH]"
set +o functrace                                            #disable trap DEBUG inherited in functions, command substitutions or subshells, normally the default setting already
shopt -s extglob                                            #enable extended pattern matching operators
function audit_DEBUG() {
  if [ "$BASH_COMMAND" != "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]               #avoid logging unexecuted commands after 'ctrl-c or 'empty+enter'
  then
    local AUDIT_CMD="$(history 1)"                          #current history command
    if ! logger -p user.info -t "$AUDIT_STR $PWD" "${AUDIT_CMD##*( )?(+([0-9])[^0-9])*( )}"
    then
      echo error "$AUDIT_STR $PWD" "${AUDIT_CMD##*( )?(+([0-9])[^0-9])*( )}"
    fi
  fi
}
function audit_EXIT() {
  local AUDIT_STATUS="$?"
  logger -p user.info -t "$AUDIT_STR" "#=== bash session ended. ==="
  exit "$AUDIT_STATUS"
}
declare -fr +t audit_DEBUG
declare -fr +t audit_EXIT
logger -p user.info -t "$AUDIT_STR" "#=== New bash session started. ===" #audit the session openning
#when a bash command is executed it launches first the audit_DEBUG(),
#then the trap DEBUG is disabled to avoid a useless rerun of audit_DEBUG() during the execution of pipes-commands;
#at the end, when the prompt is displayed, re-enable the trap DEBUG
declare -rx PROMPT_COMMAND="trap 'audit_DEBUG; trap DEBUG' DEBUG"
declare -rx BASH_COMMAND                                    #current command executed by user or a trap
declare -rx SHELLOPT                                        #shell options, like functrace
trap audit_EXIT EXIT
```

see the method explained in details here:
[http://blog.pointsoftware.ch/index.php/howto-bash-audit-command-logger](http://blog.pointsoftware.ch/index.php/howto-bash-audit-command-logger/)

cheers
Francois Scheurer

Comment: Hi Francois! Thanks a lot for sharing your code with us. I tried to send every command to an udp port by nc, adding this last line to /etc/bashrc:

Answer (score 2):

You may try [ttyrpld](http://ttyrpld.sourceforge.net/). It's more than you want because it will log the whole tty.
I haven't used it myself but the way it's working (in kernel) makes that user can't alter logs.

Comment: cool, I'll check it out. If it plays nice with everything it'll be what I need. I can change it's log files to append-only just to make sure

Comment: Cian answer using snoopy seems to be more like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use SSHLog (https://github.com/sshlog/agent/) I'm a contributor for the project.

The default configuration will record all commands and terminal output to a file.  Since your users are in a chroot jail, they will not be able to stop the process or modify the configuration.

Log files will be placed in /var/log/sshlog/sessions/ -- one file per ssh session, and will only accessible by root or members of the sshlog group.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable system auditing.

Comment: and how does one do that?

Comment: Start with the man pages for auditd and go from there.  It might not be part of the base Debian install, but the audit facility is a Linux kernel component, so the userland tools can be installed and used on any distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [grsecurity](http://grsecurity.net) patched kernel. There is a kernel option exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score -3):

bash keeps a command history of a specified size.  You the admin can set that size, and easily write a script which goes and fetches that history per user via cron.

Comment: .bash_history is for convenience, not for security. There a number of reasons for this, not the least of which being that it's user-editable (or at least appendable).